# Unable to Open an Excel file using System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

Iam trying to open an XLSX file (so that I can create a datatable )
Iam using the the below code.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oleDbCon;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAd;
oleDbCon = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
```

but when file path contains a file with extension xlsx , i get an error 
"External table is not in the expected format."

Above code works fine when file is of extention xls.

Do I have to change the connection string ?

Any help ?Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed the connection string to

```
public static string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" 
    + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

Answer (score 2):

see [Excel "External table is not in the expected format."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format)

Comment: Thanks ..Got the answer from there

Answer (score 2):

.xlsx has different [connectionstrings](http://connectionstrings.com/excel-2007)

Comment: Thanks hallie...Changed the connection string and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +"Data Source="
    + Path +";"+"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
conn.Open();  
string strExcel = "";   
OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = null;
DataSet ds = null;
strExcel="select * from [sheet1$]";
myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(strExcel, strConn);
ds = new DataSet();
myCommand.Fill(ds,"table1");   
return ds;
```

Comment: This is the same code which works well for Word 2003..Need to change the connection string to make it work for 2007