# Why the excel file not opening using this code? error occurs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;   Data Source='" + fileName + "';  Extended Properties=Excel 5.0"        

    Dim ExcelConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    ExcelConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)

    ExcelQuery = "Select * from [Sheet2$]"
    Dim ExcelCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(ExcelQuery, ExcelConnection)
    ExcelConnection.Open()

    Dim ExcelReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    ExcelReader = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader()

    While (ExcelReader.Read)


    End While
    ExcelConnection.Close()
    ExcelReader.Close()
```

Error occurs on line

```
         ExcelConnection.Open()
       External table is not in the expected format.
```

PLease help
Thank you

Comment: Please show us the connection string. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
public static string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

as your connection string. Find more information here: [Excel "External table is not in the expected format."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format).