# C# code to read Excel (html import)

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string

I trying to read Excel file which is Html type with C# code.
I'm getting an 'Unspecified error'.

This is my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='HTML Import;  // c:\1.xls
```

This is my code:

```
private string GetTableName(OleDbConnection conn)
{
   string tableName = null;
    try
    {
       conn.Open();

       var dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
       if (dt == null)
       {
          log.Error("Table schema is not available.");
          return tableName;
       }

       tableName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       log.Warn(e);
       return null;
    }
    finally
    {
       conn.Close();
    }
    return tableName;
}
```

I looked all over the Internet and Google and nobody had exactly the same issue.

I would like to understand what is wrong with my code or what does it mean the 'Unspecified Error'?!

Thanks !!!

Comment: If i remember correctly one of the windows xp service packs changed security settings around the jet driver and reading html tables but i can't find the document on the msdn i'm thinking of.  It basically restricted the ability to read html tables.  If i find it i'll come back and post the link.  good luck

Comment: check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240770 theres a section that talks about 'DisabledExtensions'

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```

Edit:

Use this connection string

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";"
```

HDR=Yes means that the header is considered as a data row and not column names (Change it depending on your needs)

IMEX=1 specify that the table contains mixed data

Answer (score 0):

for Excel 2007 change connection string as

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';
```

`ACE OLEDB 12.0` was released with Office 2007. It is possible to use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` to connect to older `.xls` (Excel 97-2003) workbooks as well.

Comment: Hi, now i get "External table is not in the expected format."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format