# How to read data from Excel in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, excel, dataset

I am trying to read datas from an uploaded xls. I have used this code part:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(fileName) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
                            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                                    connection.Open();
                            string query = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
                            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            da.Fill(ds);
```

But I get this error: External table is not in the expected format.

I am pretty sure I am giving the correct path. I was working and it is not. if it works then it wont fill the datatable. It gives an error that says that Sheet1$ object can not be found. Any help?

Comment: Can you please check the excel sheet name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string savePath = "/Assets/UploadedFiles/";
                            string fileName = "Activity.xls";
                            savePath += fileName; 
OleDbConnection conn= new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(savePath) + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'");
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    conn.Open();
    string query = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
                                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                                da.Fill(ds, "Activities");
                                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                                conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the excel version is correct? you may also want to wrap the extended properties in quotes as well. I would also recommend cleaning up your resources so you don't create memory leaks.

```
var path = Server.MapPath(fileName);

//where 8.0 may be a different version: 9 - 12?
var connectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended ""Properties=Excel 8.0""", path);
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
     connection.Open();
     command.CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
     var table = new DataTable();
     using(var reader = command.ExeucteReader())
     {
        table.Load(reader);
        return table;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread:
[Excel "External table is not in the expected format."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format)

Maybe you should change provider as they suggest.

One other option is to use the OpenXML SDK to read the excel file. This could get you started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921204.aspx

Comment: I had looked at the first link and tried but it didnt work. I still get the error "External table is not in the expected format."

Answer (score -1):

save the file in the hard disk, then add a reference to **Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library** and declare the using:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

then instantiate a class and load the file to read the cell values, example:

```
Excel.Application xlApp ;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("file.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1","A1").Value2.ToString());

xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

EDIT 1: 
If you don't want to install Office in the server, you can use the [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) that works similar, simple as (from the author page) :

```
// open xls file
Workbook book = Workbook.Load(file);
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

 // traverse cells
 foreach (Pair<Pair<int, int>, Cell> cell in sheet.Cells)
 {
     dgvCells[cell.Left.Right, cell.Left.Left].Value = cell.Right.Value;
 }

 // traverse rows by Index
 for (int rowIndex = sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; 
        rowIndex <= sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex; rowIndex++)
 {
     Row row = sheet.Cells.GetRow(rowIndex);
     for (int colIndex = row.FirstColIndex; 
        colIndex <= row.LastColIndex; colIndex++)
     {
         Cell cell = row.GetCell(colIndex);
     }
 }
```

Comment: ..that would require installing Excel on the web server which probably isn't a good idea

Comment: is there a possible way to loop this? I will have many records in the excel

Comment: And I was trying to use the first code part you wrote and for example if I say C2,C3 it give system.object instead of the content of the cell

Comment: see the documentation in the link on my post please.