# Getting error while connecting .dbf to c#. Error is External Table is not in the Expected format

Tags: c#, connection, oledbconnection

```
OleDbConnection c= new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\\Folder; Extended Properties=dBASE IV;");
c.open();
OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Table11",c);
DataSet ds=new Dataset();
da.Fill(ds);
c.Close();
```

I was trying to read .dbf table from c# and I have write above code for it, but I am getting this error:

> External Table is not in Expected Format

Comment: The problem is with your connection see [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f461a6c6-3c03-46e0-8c9b-bb04a77ed2ce)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
public static string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\\Folder; Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
OleDbConnection c= new OleDbConnection(connStr);
c.open();
OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Table11",c);
DataSet ds=new Dataset();
da.Fill(ds);
c.Close();
```

From [Excel "External table is not in the expected format."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format)

> "External table is not in the expected format." typically occurs when
>   trying to use an Excel 2007 file with a connection string that uses:
>   Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and Extended Properties=Excel 8.0

Comment: Thanks @Sonar GOnul for your reply..

But its also not working.. giving same error..

Comment: @hemant037 Are you sure you made `static` both your `conn` and excel file path? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1363480/447156

Comment: @hemant037 I think you should write `Data Source` part of your connection string full path of your excel file like `@"E:\\Folder\example.xlsx"`

Comment: @Sonar Gonul : Sir i am not trying to connect with xlsx file but i want to connnect with .dbf file..and i had tried by adding data source with full file name Like.. -> @"E:\folder\table11.dbf.... but it still not working.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
static string connStr ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Folder\sample.xlsx; Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
```