# External Table is not in the expected format when trying to create an Excel Source in SSIS 2008

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm not sure how to fix this issue.  I tried connecting an Excel source to an OLE DB Destination in SSIS 2008 R1.  When I create the Excel Connection Manager and select the file (I have chosen Excel 97 - 2003 AND even 2007) I want for the Excel Source, I click on the "Name of the Excel Sheet" column and it just says "External Table is not in the expected format".

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format

Comment: Upon entering "public static string path = @"(My file path)"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";" .. I tried putting it in as an expression.. obviously this doesn't work.  Where would I have to set this connection string?