# Unable to Connect to the Data Source with Report Builder when using a closed Excel file

Tags: excel, report

I am using Report Builder 3.0 and to get started I am using an Excel spreadsheet as my data source.  I set this up just fine.  I can connect successfully if the file is open Excel.  But if I close the file, I get the error "Unable to Connect to the data source".

This is my connection string:

Dsn=Licenses;dbq=C:\USERS\AMEADE\DOCUMENTS\licenses.xlsx;defaultdir=C:\USERS\AMEADE\DOCUMENTS;driverid=790;fil=excel 8.0;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5

Works fine if the file is open but stops working when the file is closed.  Any idea what I can do?

p.s. a similar question was asked here: [Excel "External table is not in the expected format."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format) but this was using c#

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I needed to change DSN=Licenses to Dsn=Excel.  After that, I was able to run the report with the spreadsheet closed.