# External table is not in the expected format error while trying to access Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2007, xlsx, import-from-excel

I am trying to access Excel from my vb application by using the Oledb Connection .
Here is my connection string:

```
<add key="ExcelConnection" value="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=1000;READONLY=FALSE;&quot;" />
```

Here is the code:

```
 Dim connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ExcelConnectionString)
 connection .Open()
 Dim schTbl As DataTable = connection .GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

 Dim dbAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
 Dim execQuery As String
 Dim rtnData As System.Data.DataTable

 execQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & schTbl.Rows.Item(0)("TABLE_NAME") & "]"

    dbAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(execQuery , ExcelConnectionString)

    dbAdapter.Fill(rtnDat )

    dbAdapter.Dispose()
    connection .Close()
    schTbl .Reset()
```

What my problem is that ,the above is working 70% of the times but rest of the times i am getting the following error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): External table is not in the expected format.
```

Could anyone please help me that why at times i am getting this error .Is there any way to rectify it or any other way to achive the same result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`External table is not in the expected format.` typically occurs when trying to use an Excel 2007 file.

Using the following connection string seems to fix most problems.

```
dim path as string = yourfilepath
dim connStr as string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
```

**Edit**

some times this too may fail in a case when your are using an `.xlsx` file.if that is the case you should install a JET database engine in your pc to override those errors.it is availale http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

Comment: thanks for the reply.My connection string is almost similar to what you have shown ,and regarding your next suggestion.If that is a problm  of database engine then it should throw the error everytime this is executed ,but it is only giving me error at random times.

Comment: may be you are using `.xlsx` file where you get exception.

Comment: ok as my last suggestion,is [access 2010 engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) this installed on your machiene??

Comment: i am using .xlsx file only everytime.

Comment: ok so you are getting this exception when using `.xlsx` file?? and only for some random files?

Comment: Yes only for random files (.xlsx)

Comment: i am not able to get into problem well as i am stuck with another.anyway this [excel database problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format) will help.