# Excel Sheet needs to be open to read through oleDb with c#?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I've got this big bad program all written up and everything works. But when i read in the excel sheet using oledb and c#, for some reason, the sheet cannot load unless the sheet is open in excel.

The error I get is:

> System.Data.OleDbException (0x80004005): External table is not in
>   the expected format

But it works just fine if the file is open in excel when i run the c# app. Weird. Don't whats going on.

Comment: this has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format basically you need a different connection string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format

This fixed my problem real quick like