# SSIS Package Issue with Excel Connection Manager

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

In my local machine, SQL job runs perfectly. Inside SQL job there is SSIS package which grab Excel data and load into the Staging table. There is **Microsoft Excel 2010** in my System.

Now the issue is on Development Server.
Same job with same SSIS package which in Network folder run with issue. The Development server consist a **Excel 2013**

I don have enough reputation to show the screenshot of the error message. Here is the error saying.

```
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. 
Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine"  
Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "External table is not in the expected format.".  
End Error  Error: 2015-07-10 14:16:05.52     
Code: 0xC020801C     
Source: Data Flow Task Excel Source [2]     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed. 

Error: 2015-07-10 14:16:05.52     
Code: 0xC0047017     
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     
Description: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  

Error: 2015-07-10 14:16:05.52     
Code: 0xC004700C     
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     
Description: One or more component failed validation
```

Comment: 1)It Consists a Excel File Path. **\\nwhfile1\nwh\SharedPrivateFolders\IT_Finance\ITProgramming_FinanceAccounting\BOA_Cleared_test\nhllc_paid_chks.xlsx**    and Excel version 2007

Comment: Are you using the same file between servers?

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format)

Answer (score 1):

also, two things
1) make sure your excel file is NOT open
2) ssis cant use excel in 64bit mode, change your deployment settings to use 32 bit runtime (if youre using an sql job, check the settings)

Comment: See this URL for details on how to specify 32 bit driver http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534651/How-to-solve-SSIS-error-code-0xC020801C-0xC004700C