# An unhandled exception Additional information: External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: External table is not in the expected format.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Projects\test.xlsx";
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connStr))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adaptor.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
```

adaptor.Fill(ds); ==> Additional information: External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format

Answer (score 1):

This code is working, check if the file location is correct and also if the sheet name is `Sheet1`.

The code is tested on my local system and no exception are thrown.

Comment: Additional information: The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.
this is the exception

Comment: That means your excel file is already open, by your code or in the explorer.

Comment: I closed all open windows except visual studio,  
this exception is showen
( Additional information: External table is not in the expected format. )