# External table is not in the expected format in c#

Tags: c#, excel-2007, xlsx, oledbconnection

I am trying to work with .xlsx file with the below Connection string in  my C# code .

```
public static string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
   Data Source=@@filename;
   Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;
   IMEX=0;
   HDR=YES;
   TypeGuessRows=0;
   ImportMixedTypes=Text""";
```

But whenever I am running the Code I am getting Error

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: Running _what_ code?

Comment: its C# code for xlsx files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1139390/447156?

Comment: not able to find any solution from above link ...:(