# I'm trying to write a filter in Excel that considers multiple criteria AND/OR in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet I need to filter based on the following criteria:

if
any of columns, 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33, or 36 contain value1
AND
any of columns 4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34, or 37 contain value2

for example, let's consider a table that contains a list of clients in the first row
and the technicians performing a service in the rows above (column header would be date of service)

I want to know all clients who had "Bob" as the first technician and "Tim" as the second on any dates

If the data were in a SQL database instead of Excel, I guess it would be something like:

```
    SELECT * FROM DATA
    WHERE
      (COL3 = "Bob" OR
       COL6 = "Bob" OR
       COL9 = "Bob"
       ...
       COL36 = "Bob") 
    AND
      (COL4 = "Tim" OR
       COL7 = "Tim" OR
       COL10 = "Tim" OR
       ...
       COL37 = "Tim")
```

The PC I am using is locked down -- all I have is Office

I cannot export to CSV and run a script on it
I cannot run a Powershell script since I do not have Admin access and cannot run the command:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

I need to either do this with a filter, advanced filter, or a VBA (or VBS?) script

(simplified) data would be something like:
(I know the columns don't match with the numbers above -- I cut it down for simplicity)

| Customer |  | Day1 | Day2 |  | Day3 | Day4 |  | Day5 | Day6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 89839977 |  | Tom | John |  | Doug | Tony |  | Max | Sam |
| 94078908 |  | Doug | Tony |  | Jim | Sam |  | Juan | Sam |
| 93893980 |  | Mike | Sam |  | Max | Dave |  | Tom | Fred |
| 89208300 |  | Jim | Tim |  | Tom | Fred |  | Bob | Paul |
| 90890898 |  | Max | Tony |  | Mike | Sam |  | Doug | Dave |
| 39088370 |  | Doug | Paul |  | Bob | Joe |  | Jim | Tim |

Only the lines for clients 89208300 and 39088370 should remain
While perhaps not apparent in the data above, because of the way the query is structured, only, the technicians are in 2 teams. "Bob" will only be at a client on an odd days and 'Tim' will only be at clients on even days.
Each technician may see the same client multiple days a week or see multiple clients in a day

Is what I'm trying to do possible given the constraints I have for working.
The spreadsheet is over 4,000 lines long and doing it by hand with over 30 columns is tedious, time-consuming, and error-prone

Thanks in advance

**2023/11/23  EDIT**:
I've updated the table to include blank columns (and list of columns) more representative of the data I'll be using.  I left it out initially for the sake of brevity; I didn't think a blank column would make any difference (not knowing about the workings of the VBA function Range.CurrentRegion)

Thank everyone who has responded with helpful suggestions so far.

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correctly. Would something like this do what you mean? `=LET(s,SEQUENCE(,11,4,3),chck,LAMBDA(range,seq,name,BYROW(INDEX(range,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),seq),LAMBDA(b,--OR(b=name)))),FILTER(A2:A7,chck(A2:AN7,s,"Bob")*chck(A2:AN7,s+1,"Tim"),"No matches"))`

Comment: Bob" will only be at a client on an odd days ? Bob is at 39088370 on Oct4

Comment: Do you have MS365 i.e. is excel formula an option? Which of the columns is column 4? Are you aware that the columns' offset is 3, not 2 required for odd and even?

Comment: (I fixed the days for "Bob")  -- I do realize that the offsets for the columns are different, that the even columns contain odd dates and that odd columns contain even dates.  The data should above are just some sample data I created on the spot to show a simplified, cut-down version of the problem I'm trying to solve.  There is a selection criterion for one set of columns and a different one for the other set.  I only need the rows that have any value in the first set of columns that meet the 1stcriterion AND any column from the 2nd set that meet the second criterion.

Answer (score 0):

No code here, but too long for a comment.

a) There is no OR-functionality in Excel AutoFilter on different columns, so you can't use that.

b) A VBA code should be rather simple, just read your data into an 2-Dimensional array, loop over all rows and check if Bob and Tim are present. Question is what you want to do with the result - you didn't mention that.

c) You could use SQL to query your sheet (keywords: ADODB). As you have already an idea about the SQL command, maybe that's a way to go. Have a look for example to [Use SQL in Excel VBA to access other Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42726971/7599798) to get an idea.

d) Add helper columns to your sheet (that's often the easiest solution). This column could have a formula like

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("Bob",$A4:$AK2,0)<MATCH("Tim",$A5:$AL2,0),1,""),"")
```

Now you will have an 1 for every row where Bob visited the customer before Tim. Use that column to set a filter.

Comment: The order doesn't matter -- only that both Bob and Tim visited.  In the data above for customer 89208300, Tim was there on Oct 2 and Bob on Oct 5

Comment: As for what to do with the results, either writing a new sheet or hiding the lines don't match would work equally well

Comment: You could make an `AND` formula instead, something like this (untested, just to give you the idea): `=IFERROR(AND(MATCH("Bob",$A4:$AK2,0)>0,MATCH("Tim",$A5:$AL2,0))>0,FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, r As Long, s As Long
    Dim ColCnt As Long, RowCnt As Long, bMatch As Boolean
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes()
    ' modify as needed
    Const KEY1 = "Bob" 'odd day
    Const KEY2 = "Tim" 'even day
    ' Load data
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    k = 1
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 1 To ColCnt)
    ' Load header
    For r = 1 To ColCnt
        arrRes(k, r) = arrData(1, r)
    Next
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To RowCnt
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To ColCnt Step 2
            If StrComp(arrData(i, j), KEY1, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                For s = LBound(arrData, 2) + 2 To ColCnt Step 2
                    If StrComp(arrData(i, s), KEY2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        k = k + 1
                        For r = 1 To ColCnt
                            arrRes(k, r) = arrData(i, r)
                        Next
                        bMatch = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If bMatch Then Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Write output to a new sheet
    If k > 2 Then
        Sheets.Add
        Range("A1").Resize(k, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

---

***Update:***

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim aCol1, aCol2, j, s  '**
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, r As Long  '**
    Dim ColCnt As Long, RowCnt As Long, bMatch As Boolean
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes()
    ' modify as needed
    Const KEY1 = "Bob" 'odd day
    Const KEY2 = "Tim" 'even day
    ' Load data
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    k = 1
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 1 To ColCnt)
    ' Load header
    For r = 1 To ColCnt
        arrRes(k, r) = arrData(1, r)
    Next
    ' Loop through data
    aCol1 = Array(7, 9, 10, 13, 17, 21, 27)
    aCol2 = Array(8, 11, 15, 22, 29)
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To RowCnt
        For Each j In aCol1  '**
            If StrComp(arrData(i, j), KEY1, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                For Each s In aCol2  '**
                    If StrComp(arrData(i, s), KEY2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        k = k + 1
                        For r = 1 To ColCnt
                            arrRes(k, r) = arrData(i, r)
                        Next
                        bMatch = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If bMatch Then Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Write output to a new sheet
    If k > 2 Then
        Sheets.Add
        Range("A1").Resize(k, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: This looks promising -- I assume it's VBA?  
Looking at this, it makes some assumptions about the layout of the data
suppose instead I had    

columns1 = [7,9,10,13,17,21,27] // for "Bob"
columns2  = [8,11,15,22,29]       // for "Tim"  

assuming that both "Bob" before "Tim" and "Tim" before "Bob" are both valid

Comment: I take a depper dive into this -- I'll try to find some reference to the objects you reference above in either the VBA or VBS (depending on the language you're using above) for Excel -- 
A link to that would be great -- I seem to be having some difficulty finding it

Comment: It's a VBA code. Please check the updated code.

Comment: thanks -- this looks much more like what I need, thanks for the reference.  When I try to use it in the actual data, since the spreadsheet I have with real data contains blank columns, the `arrData` returned by `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value` only contains 2 columns (the 3rd column in my spreadsheet is blank)  Looking at the documentation for Range, I don't see a method/property that will return the entire spreadsheet of data in a large array (matrix).  If looks like I might have to instead use .Cells and iterate over each directly instead of using the arrData copy?

Comment: If your table starts from col A, you could use `arrData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value`. Otherwise please show the layout of sheet in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far.
I've updated my question to include blank columns

Answer (score 0):

### Filter Data

```
=LET(data,A2:G7,oTech,I3,eTech,J3,
        oCols,L3:L5,eCols,M3:M5,if_not_found,"Nope",
    td,DROP(data,,1),
    od,CHOOSECOLS(td,oCols),
    ed,CHOOSECOLS(td,eCols),
    f,BYROW(SEQUENCE(ROWS(td)),LAMBDA(r,
        ISNUMBER(XMATCH(oTech,CHOOSEROWS(od,r)))
        *ISNUMBER(XMATCH(eTech,CHOOSEROWS(ed,r))))),
FILTER(data,f,if_not_found))
```

- Instead of `L3:L5` and `M3:M5` you could e.g. hardcode `{1;3;5}` and `{2;4;6}` respectively.

[image]

**Starting Point**

- The following is a basic formula to return rows where all (both) of the technicians were found.

```
=LET(data,A2:G7,techs,J2:J3,if_not_found,"Nope",
    td,DROP(data,,1),
    cc,BYROW(td,LAMBDA(r,COUNT(XMATCH(techs,r)))),
FILTER(data,cc=COUNTA(techs),if_not_found))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:**

With MS365, you can use the `FILTER` function with `BYROW`, `PRODUCT` and `COUNTIF` to return the desired results. For example:

[image: filter_byrow.png]

In the example shown above, the formula in cell `A13` is:

```
=FILTER(A2:G7, BYROW(B2:G7, LAMBDA(r, PRODUCT(COUNTIF(r, B10:C10)))), "None")
```

The `COUNTIF` function returns a separate count for each technician in the range `B10:C10`, which are then multiplied using the `PRODUCT` function to determine if both "Bob" **AND** "Tim" were found in each row.

**Note:** since your actual data set contains thousands of rows and many more columns than your sample data, it would probably be best to move the criteria cells and results to a separate worksheet.

**OPTION 2:**

Advanced Filter can also be used if you prefer to filter the data in place (or if you're using an older version of Excel). The setup for this method would look something like this:

[image: advance_filter_setup.png]

In this example, the criteria range that will be used with Advanced Filter is located in range `L1:L2`, where the formula in cell `L2` is:

```
=PRODUCT(COUNTIF(B2:G2, $I$2:$J$2))>0
```

**Note:** with older versions of Excel, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when inputting the above formula.

There are 3 rules when using formulas in the criteria range:

1. No heading
2. The formula must result in True or False
3. The formula should reference the first row of the data range

Next, select any cell within the data range, then go to **Data > Sort & Filter > Advanced** to open the Advanced Filter dialog box:

[image: advanced_filter.png]

The list range should be identified automatically. If it's not, then select the entire data range to be filtered. Finally, select the criteria range, including the cell with the formula **AND** the blank cell above it, and click OK. The results should look something like this:

[image: advanced_filter_resutls.png]

To clear the filter, use the **Clear** button found in the same **Sort & Filter** section on the Ribbon. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new helper column with formula `=AND(COUNTIF(),COUNTIF())`. Apply filter on helper column = TRUE, then copy filtered rows to new sheet and delete the added column.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub myfilter()

    Const N1 = "Bob"
    Const N2 = "Tim"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsData As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, c As Long, f As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsResult = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    With wsData
        ' find end column and row
        c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' criteria N1 and N2 both in same row
        f = "=AND(COUNTIF(RC2:RC" & c & ",""" & N1 & """)>0," & _
                 "COUNTIF(RC2:RC" & c & ",""" & N2 & """)>0)"
        
        ' apply formula to end helper column
        c = c + 1
        .Cells(2, c).Resize(lastrow - 1).FormulaR1C1 = f
        
        ' filter rows on helper= true
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow, c)
           .AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:=True
           .Copy wsResult.Range("A1")
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        ' cleanup delete helpers
        .Columns(c).Delete
        wsResult.Columns(c).Delete
    End With
    MsgBox "Result on " & wsResult.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```