# Exporting and Importing xlsx file throwing exception in c#

Tags: c#

I am exporting a file in xlsx format after saving the file i am importing it back, but while importing it back I am getting `External table is not in the expected format` exception. However when i am opening the imported file and just save it again it work like a charm and I am able to import it back

For Exporting

```
content type - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
```

For Importing

```
Excel connection string - "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "{1};HDR=Yes;IMEX=1" + (char)34 + ";";
```

Comment: could you please check the following solution? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format) Best regards.

Comment: @KevinH. H , My solution and one you suggested are similar. My code is working if I explicitly save the exported excel before importing but when I import the excel without saving it throws exception.