# SSIS Package under Project in Catalogue is Failing

Tags: excel, ssis

We have a project under which there are multiple packages tagged, earlier this used to run fine. But suddenly in one of our project wherever we are using excel connections those packages are getting failed with a common error saying Acquire connection failed and the external table is not in the correct format.
On the contrary when i run these packages individually by doing no changes these run successfully.

Comment: What is the full error? There might be more errors explaining the acquire connection issue. Not much to go on with your question.

Comment: the exact error message is External is table is not in correct format. Then Acquire connection to excel connection failed. Also when i just take this package and run in visual studio it runs successfully with no changes. And this is happening only for say excel connection in all over the projects and packages. Our job is running through SQL Agent which has permission over all folders

Comment: External table is not in the correct format usually happens when you use the wrong jet driver to connect to an Excel file, please have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139390/excel-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format) concerning using the correct jet driver in your Excel source connection string

Comment: Thanks for the update , but the solution was as weird as the problem did a server reboot and all back to normal. So its solved thanks for the check